# Are there any wysiwyg editors for simply raw code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find some jQuery/JavaScript wysiwyg editors that are simply made specifically for editing raw code. Don't need any formatting and needs to only accept plain text.

The most important feature is to have line numbers, It would be even good if it colors the code in real time.

Light weight solutions are always preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) does this and is very good. [Here's a demo with line numbers](http://codemirror.net/demo/activeline.html).

Answer (score 2):

http://ace.ajax.org/ looks like it. It's have syntax highliting and line numbers.

Live demo: http://ace.ajax.org/build/kitchen-sink.html